# How to fetch completion status based on sub records

Tags: sql-server

My data looks like below:

```
AssocName AssocNo Cour SubCour Compltn
Mark      1       A    A1      12/7
Mark      1       A    A2      14/7 
Mark      1       A    A3      13/7

Tom       2       A    A1      12/7
Tom       2       A    A2      13/7
Tom       2       A    A3      NULL
```

Each course has 3 sub courses and the course is marked complete only when all 3 are marked complete else it’s not complete.
The latest date of completion of sub course is taken as date of completion of course

I want my output as below:

```
AssocName AssocNo Cour Status     Date SubCour Compltn 
    Mark      1     A  Complete   14/7 A1      12/7
    Mark      1     A  Complete   14/7 A2      14/7 
    Mark      1     A  Complete   14/7 A3      13/7
    Tom       2     A  InComplete Null A1      12/7
    Tom       2     A  InComplete Null A2      13/7 
    Tom       2     A  InComplete Null A3      NULL
```

Any inputs on this would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried doing it with `GROUP BY` ? Please show us what you have tried

Comment: What is the type of the `Compltn` column?

Comment: Hi @twitter investor, AssocNo column value for Tom will 2 or 1. Your sample data it was 2 but your expected output it is 1. Is there any reason or logic?

Comment: @rahul biswas I’ve made the change. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @tim biegeleisen it’s a date type

Comment: Hi @twitterinvestor please check my answer below. Hope it'll meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data no WHERE is added. If you want data for a particular month then add it in where clause. Check it and hope it'll meet expectations.

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT c.AssocName, c.AssocNo, c.Cour
     , CASE WHEN t.tot_subc = 3 AND t.null_date_count = 1
               THEN 'Incomplete'
            ELSE 'Complete'
       END status
     , CONVERT(varchar(5), (CASE WHEN t.null_date_count = 1 THEN NULL ELSE t.max_Compltn END), 3) date
     , c.SubCour
     , CONVERT(varchar(5),c.Compltn,3)Compltn
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN (SELECT AssocNo, Cour, COUNT(SubCour) tot_subc, MAX(Compltn) max_Compltn
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Compltn IS NULL THEN 1 END) null_date_count
FROM Course
GROUP BY AssocNo, Cour) t
        ON c.AssocNo = t.AssocNo
       AND c.Cour = t.Cour
ORDER BY c.AssocNo;
```

Please check the url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b290b56daed7091e98cb25f72c266aa5

Comment: Hi @twitter investor, in above example counted null value for taking a major decision if course is completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is along the lines of what you want here:

```sql
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AssocNo, Cour) =
                 COUNT(Compltn) OVER (PARTITION BY AssocNo, Cour)
            THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'InComplete' END AS Status
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY AssocNo, Cour, SubCour;
```

The above logic uses a `COUNT` trick as this function will count a `NULL` value as `NULL`.  Should the two counts agree, it implies that the `Compltn` column has only non `NULL` values present.

Comment: But I don’t think this accounts for the Date column for the course that I want though,does it?